# How to return from asynchronous call using jquery?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, asynchronous, geocoding

I tried to use the callback function but it still has no effect. Here is the HTML:

```
<form action="{% url 'seller_details' %}" method="post" id="seller_details">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        <div class="heading">PERSONAL INFORMATION</div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="wd25">Full Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" name="full_name" value="{{full_name}}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mobile Number</td>
                <td><input type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number" value="{{mobile}}" name="mobile"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Store Address</td>
                <td><textarea rows="5" placeholder="Store Address" name="pickup_address" value="{{pickup_address}}"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

Then I tried to validate the form and submit the form using **submit handler** of jQuery validate

```
$("#seller_details").validate({
    rules: {
        full_name: "required",
        pickup_address:"required",
    },
    messages: {
        full_name: "Please enter Name",
        mobile: "Please enter Mobile Number",
       pickup_address:"Please enter address",
    },
    submitHandler: function(form){
        var form = $(form).serialize()

        codeLatLng(storeGeoAddress);

        console.log(latitude)
        console.log(longitude)

        $.ajax({        
            type: "post",
            url: "{% url 'seller_details' %}",     
            data: form + "&csrfmiddlewaretoken=" + '{{csrf_token}}' + '&latitude=' + latitude + '&longitude=' + longitude,
```

I used the following **asynchronous function** called **geocoder** to get the **latitude** and **longitude** of the address submitted

```
function codeLatLng(callback) {
    var address = $("textarea[name=pickup_address]").val();
    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    callback(results[0]);
                } else {
                    alert("No results found");
                }
            } 
            else {
                alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
            }
        });
    }
}

function storeGeoAddress(addr) {     
    latitude = addr.geometry.location.lat();
    longitude = addr.geometry.location.lng();
}
```

The problem I am facing here is that I am not able to gather the values of latitude and longitude so that I can give it back to my submit handler so that it can post the values? What can I do in such a scenario? Thank you

**Latitude** and **Longitude** are globally defined here

> console.log(latitude)  console.log(longitude) are not able to log anything

Is there any Way by Which i can make **Submit Handler** as my callback function?

Comment: What is the scope of your `latitude` and `longitude` variables? If they're within scope of both functions then what you have should work, although it's rather odd placing a JSON string in the querystring of a request. You would be best just sending a plain object and letting jQuery encode it for you.

Comment: What you have will not work regardless of the scope of `latitude and longitude`. `$.ajax` will run before the `storeGeoAddress` callback gets fired because the logic in `storeGeoAddress` is async. You need to perform your AJAX in your callback. Then you can also sack of the nasty global variables.

Comment: both variables are global

Comment: then in that case the submit handler should be the callback

Comment: Any Chance that i can make submit handler as callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises to the rescue.

jQuery has a Promise implementation that is useful enough for your situation. How about this.

First, write a geocode-Helper that wraps Google's callback-based API method and returns the *promise* of a resolved address instead:

```
function geocodeAsync(addrString) {
    var result = $.Deferred();

    if ( !(geocoder && geocoder.geocode) ) {
        result.reject("geocoder not defined");
    } else {
        geocoder.geocode({address: addrString}, function (results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results.length) {
                    result.resolve(results[0]);
                } else {
                    result.reject("No results found");
                }
            }
            else {
                result.reject("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
            }
        });
    }

    return result.promise();
}
```

Now, things get easy. You can use that function in exactly the same way you would use jQuery's Ajax functions:

```
$("#seller_details").validate({
    rules: {/* ... */},
    messages: {/* ... */},
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        var address = $(form).find("textarea[name=pickup_address]").val();

        geocodeAsync(address).done(function (geocodeResult) {
            var otherParams = {
                'parameter[]': JSON.stringify(parameter),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}',
                latitude: geocodeResult.geometry.location.lat(),
                longitude: geocodeResult.geometry.location.lng()
            },
            postBody = [ $(form).serialize(), $.param(otherParams) ].join('&');

            $.post("{% url 'seller_details' %}", postBody).done(function (result) {
                // whatever you want to do on POST success
            }).fail(function (jqXhr, status, error) {
                // seller_details update failed
            });
        }).fail(function (reason) {
            alert("Geocoding failed because: " + reason);
        });
    }
});
```

No global variables needed and when reading the code you see exactly what happens.

Relevant documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/

Comment: what is results in else part? i think it should be result.reject ?

Comment: @AdrafeRinzzler Right, that was a typo. I should have thought of better variable names than `result` and `results`.

Comment: var address = $(form).find("textarea[name=pickup_address]").val();

Comment: postBody = [ $(form).serialize(), $.param(otherParams) ].join('&'); says unrecognized exp ...why so?

Comment: `$(form).find()` is not the same as `form.find()`. I also can't see a syntax error there. `[ $(form).serialize(), $.param(otherParams) ].join('&')` is equally valid. Are you using the code as I posted it or have you made changes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105554/discussion-between-adrafe-rinzzler-and-tomalak).

Answer (score 2):

You're in callback hell! This is a fairly common problem to have in javascript. The way you return "synchronously" from an asynchronous call is through a Promise. Either that or you have to pass along a chain of callbacks to handle the various steps that must occur.

My favorite JS Promise implementation is https://github.com/cujojs/when, and I recommend you follow this guide: http://blog.briancavalier.com/async-programming-part-1-it-s-messy/

Comment: what about jquery solutions?

Comment: Any Chance that i can make submit handler as callback?

Answer (score 1):

You can still create the callback inside the submitHandler

```
codeLatLng(function(addr){
    var latitude = addr.geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = addr.geometry.location.lng();

    console.log(latitude)
    console.log(longitude)

    $.ajax(...);
});
```